# php unable to send mail

Tags: php, email, joomla

I'm trying to set up a php script to send an email on a server with a joomla installed, I got the some script working in other project and is working fine. 
I'm using this script on a landing page separate from Joomla. I had check the phpinfo and this is what it's show.

```
mail.add_x_header   On  On
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   no value    no value
```

I'm wondering if the joomla is interfering with the mail function of php or if the function is not properly set up in php.ini

Thank you!

Comment: The sendmail path needs to be set. Joomla probably has smtp set up to send mails

Comment: Each PHP page requested is parsed on it's own so if you don't include joomla into your script then there is no way for the two to interfere with one another. As Pierre said check your sendmail path.

Comment: Thank you! I will try set the sendmail path.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are lot of plugins you can install.

Or,

Try PHPMailer. I have used it in the past. It's very easy to implement.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It means you haven't correctly setup your mail server in Joomla!

To setup the mail server go to Global Configurations > Server > Mail settings

Choose the best option for your mail settings from the dropdown and setup!

If you have a cPanel, go to Mail section and find info about your email, authentication type and more!

Hope this helps!